Unable to Locate Google Apps Script for Web App Created in Classic Google Sites
We created a Google Web App in 2019 using the classic version of Google Sites. The associated Google Apps Script was accessible via the "Manage Site" menu at sites.google.com. However, since the transition to the new Google Sites, we are unable to locate the Apps Script associated with the web app.
Steps Taken:

Searched in Google Drive and script.google.com.

Verified that the Google account used for the script has access to all relevant files.

Checked the Google Apps Script Dashboard but didn’t find the project.

Looked through Google Sites (new and classic versions) for any possible references to the script.
Question:

Is there a way to recover the Google Apps Script from a classic Google Site web app?

Could it have been archived, or does Google provide a way to retrieve lost scripts?




Any guidance on retrieving the script or understanding what might have happened during the transition from classic to new Google Sites would be greatly appreciated.

See Convert your classic Sites to new Sites

Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79005218/

From the documentation:

Any Google Apps Scripts created within Classic Sites neither migrate to converted new sites, nor are included in Takeout export.
The original classic site will appear in “Deleted Sites” on the classic Sites homepage. It will indicate that it was deleted by Google. After a classic site is deleted, any Apps Scripts that were created within the classic site are also gradually deleted.

